# Selecting fields on Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, select, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find information about how to select only certain fields of an entity using Spring Data (I'm using JPA). I want to select only specific information of an entity, the repository interfaces gives you the ways to return the information of the WHOLE entity!. Some times I only need 2 or 3 fields of an entity and returning 20,30, ...100.. fields may be a little overkill.

This kind of functionality is something that I would do using Hibernate Criteria Projections, or even JPA  "SELECT NEW ...." queries. Don't know if it is possible with Spring Data.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that it's not possible yet. Checking the issue tracker, I found this. [DATAJPA-51](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-51).

Comment: Just create the query, slap it in a `@Query` annotation and run your code. That should still work...

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is return a `List<Object[]>` from repository. Then in your service class iterate over this list and manually create the object you need. Sample repository method

```
@Query("select el.moduleId, el.threadId from ExceptionLog el")
public List<Object[]> tempQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also do it in this way

```
SomeDataPOJO{
    required col1
    required col2
}
```

and then write query like this

```
@Query("select new SomeDataPOJO from requiredTable where xyz="abc")
public List<SomeDataPoJO> tempQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not plain Spring Data but did you consider using Springs `JdbcTemplate`? Its also in the Context if you use Spring Boots Autoconfiguration and has several handlers for transforming results of the Query.

For Example for the Query `SELECT a, b FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?` you could use

```
String query = "SELECT a, b FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?";
List<Pair<String,Integer>> employees = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
query, new Object[] { id }, new ExampleRowMapper());
```

Where the `ExampleRowMapper` transforms each row from the result into your given Return type (`Pair<String, Integer>` in this case) and could look like

```
public class ExampleRowMapper implements RowMapper<Pair<String, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public Pair<String, Integer> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return Pair.of(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
    }
}
```

Example adapted from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate where you find more information.

Of course its not as typesafe as a JPQL as the Query is "raw" or "native" SQL but at least the response is again typesafe and I like it more than to return `Object[]` or something.